# How to display variable text from a text file in textview in android like in news flash?

Tags: android, textview

I want to add a horizontal textbox in my android application in which i want to show news flash (running text like in news channels). I want to display such content from a text file or an online source. How can I implement such problem.

Please Help!!!

Thank You In Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in xml

```
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
```